# React - pass props/state to rendered HTML string?

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have stored a text template as an HTML string on the server which is passed up to the client to be rendered. Is it possible to render this HTML string in such a way that it can access it's parent component `state`/`props`? I've tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`, both of which render the string as HTML, but render `{props.text}` as a literal string, rather than a reference to the component's `props`.

For example, on the server I have stored:

```
<div>Welcome to my app</div>
<div>{props.message}</div>
<div>Have fun</div>
```

And the component

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { state }
},
    WelomeBody = (props) => {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{"__html": props.state.welcomeMessageBody}} />
        )
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(WelomeBody)
```

but this results in:

```
Welcome to my app
{props.message}
Have fun
```

Is there a way that this can be rendered so as to access the value of `props.message`, rather than just rendering it literally?

Comment: How do you imagine this to work? What you have is not an HTML string but jsx. jsx get's transpiled by e.g. babel to javascript code. You can't just render it and expect it to be interpreted as actual jsx. You would need some kind of transpiler in your frontend application. It's just the wrong approach to do it like this. Why not provide the actual component as javascript and get the props required for rendering as json from the server?

Comment: @trixn thanks for your feedback. So my example is somewhat simplified, of course. The actual data on the server is an email template, which I want to both show to the client (and pass in some of their data for good UI) but then send from the server. I can think of alternate ways to do this, but was curious about handling it via `props`, `state` etc., but I can see that it's not that easy. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: As you already have a perfect rendering engine in place in your frontend, which is called `react`, i don't see why you would want to implement a rather poor solution yourself. Just take our email markup and make a react component with the same markup. Then you will only need to fetch props as json from the server. Will probably cost you not more than some minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you have in mind is to send down a React component (in JSX syntax) from your server to your client and have the client somehow rehydrate/compile it into an actual, working component, this is not achievable that easily.

When you build and bundle your React app, only components that are statically referenced/imported in your application at compile time can be used at runtime on the browser.

So, in order to dynamically render a component from a template and embed variables into it, your choices are:

1. Render it into final HTML on your server, send down that HTML and have a simple React component perform `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for it. But, like you've already observed, that content has to be the full HTML code, no templates, variables, JSX, etc. Everything is string and HTML at this point, no more processing.
2. Alternatively, send down a **Markdown** document and have a [Markdown component](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) parse it into HTML and display it.
3. Create a sophisticated component that can receive a string, parse it, tokenize it, substitute values in it, etc. Essentially, create your own template-processing component that can read a template (the string sent down from your server) and embed the appropriate values into it.

A simple solution (to substitute values into a template) would be:

```
function Filler(props) {
    let html = props.template;
    Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
        if (key !== "template")
            html = html.replace("{" + key + "}", props[key]);
    });

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />;
}
```

and use it like

```
<Filler template={"<h1>Hello, {firstname} {lastname}</h1>"} firstname="John" lastname="Doe" />
```

But again, this is far from a full-fledged actual React component.

Comment: Thanks very much for such a comprehensive answer - I was originally leaning toward a solution similar to what you proposed in #3, but thought I'd see if there were any more basic out-of-the-box solutions available. Appreciate your time and expertise.